# Резиновый макет - составной фон

Tags: html, css

Есть верстка для резинового макета вида:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  background: /* картинка шириной 1400px */
}
main {
  background: /* картинка шириной 1400px */
}
footer {
  background: /* картинка шириной 1400px */
}
```

Ввиду того, что 1400px - не лучший вариант для большинства бюджетных ноутбуков и для почти всех нетбуков, было принято решение об 'укорачивании' сайта по бокам, благо есть куда.
Но при этом нужно сохранить боковые части фонов.
Т.е. получается примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Серое - margin-ы wrapper-а
- Красное - шапка, зеленое - контент, синеее - футер
- Темные оттенки цветов - часть блоков, которая будет скрываться, если ширина экрана меньше 1400px

Я не совсем понимаю, как это верно реализовать.
Можно, например, поместить внутрь header-а div, в котором будет все. И дальше задать div-у ширину 1200px и `margin: 0 auto`. Есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо статичной ширины просто ограничить по минимальному и максимальному размеру соответственно min-width, max-width

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `margin` для вложенных блоков, и если необходимо `padding` для `wrapper`.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>Header
    </header>
    <main>Main
    </main>
    <footer>Footer
    </footer>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {background: pink;padding:10px;}

header {background:red;height:200px;margin: 0px 20px;}

main {background:green;height:200px;margin: 0px 20px;}

footer {background:yellow;height:200px;margin: 0px 20px;}
```

Пример можешь посмотреть здесь:
https://jsfiddle.net/NikitaSmith/7rvgq1pg/6/